# !Bloomberg vba price import issue

Tags: excel, vba, bloomberg

for months I've been using a macro created by a collegue that worked flawlessly, but for some reason It stopped 2 days ago, I'm a bit unfamiliar with programming (please excuse me) but it looks like something happened to the Bloomberg commands that were used to extract data (price of securities listed)

this is the error message I get:

[image]

and this is the macro until the line that it stops

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
Sub update()

Dim wbk As Workbook 'This workbook
Set wbk = ThisWorkbook
Dim path As String
path = wbk.path
Dim oBBG As New BLP_DATA_CTRLLib.BlpData
Dim date_string As String
date_string = CStr(CLng(Now()))

Dim row As Long
Dim col As Long
Dim vtSecurities As Variant
Dim vtFields As Variant
Dim vtData As Variant
Dim d1 As Date
Dim tmp As String

With wbk.Sheets(1)
        .Activate

        .Cells(1, 1) = "TICKER"
        .Cells(1, 2) = "LAST_PRICE"
        .Cells(1, 3) = "DESCRIPTION"
        .Cells(1, 4) = "CURRENCY"
        .Cells(1, 5) = "PRICE_CLOSE_DATE"
        .Cells(1, 6) = "LAST_UPDATE"
        .Cells(1, 7) = "PX_CLOSE_DT"
        d1 = Now()
        .Cells(1, 8) = "Last Refresh"
        .Cells(1, 9) = d1

        .Cells(5, 9) = "Macro Guideline"
        .Cells(6, 9) = "1- Copy Ticker in first column"
        .Cells(7, 9) = "2- Click on the update button"
        .Cells(8, 9) = "3- Ticker not found will be move into the Deleted Table. They will not appear in the Bloomberg Extract table."


        'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)
        row = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
        'Find the last non-blank cell in row 1
        col = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        vtSecurities = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(row, 1)))
        vtFields = Array("PX LAST", "Name", "CRNCY", "PX_LAST", "LAST_UPDATE_DT", "PX_CLOSE_DT")
        **vtData = oBBG.BLPSubscribe(vtSecurities, vtFields)**
```

I'm sorry if anything is missing, I've verified and the Bloomberg data type library is in the checked references.

thanks!

Comment: When it errors, hit "Debug". In the "Locals" pane check out that `vtSecurities` variable. Make sure that is being set correctly. Perhaps the `WorksheetFunction.Transpose (.Range(Cells(2,1), cells(row,1)))` isn't grabbing the right data anymore.

Comment: I've looked and they all seem ok, it is grabbing the security cusip as it should

Comment: You may want to tell us what error you are getting instead of making it an image as many people here are at work and cannot view images.

Comment: of course, sorry, the error reads as:
 run-time error '-2147221231 (80040111)'

Automation error
ClassFactory cannot supply requested class

Answer (score 0):

FYI, Bloomberg updated their Desktop API. All the old API calls won't work. You will need to change your code to the new API, or I'm told that Bloomberg can revert your login to the old API for an additional month if you ask them.

Comment: yeah I went ahead and asked Bloomberg directly and that what they came back with, thanks for the help!